# How can I create a variable that contain class to be used in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I have been searching through the webs for clues about a variable that can contain class object, and I found nothing. I believe there is some way to store an information about a class in a variable to be used in intent. Sorry for the bad explanation, here is the code to illustrate what I mean.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button startBtn, chooseLevelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        chooseLevelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseLevelBtn);

        class classVariable = "Level001Activity.class";
        /*
         * I want a variable like this where I can store the Activity.class
         * So that I can use a function to determine the last level played,
         * and so when the player press playBtn, it would automatically
         * send the intent to the latest level
         * Now, how do I achieve this ?
         */

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    classVariable);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

P.S I will be getting the last level played information from a json file I store inside the internal storage of the device. Or any better method is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about `Intent i = (this, Level001Activity.class);` ?

Comment: @Christine I'm assuming the variable is decided dynamically at runtime.

Comment: My point was mainly to remove the quotes :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You need to make it `Class` rather than `class` and remove the quotes as it shouldn't be a `String`:

```
Class<? extends Activity> classVariable = Level001Activity.class;
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, I should point out that if you want to store these classes in Json, you could use a `String` and use `Class.forName` to get the corresponding  `Class` objects.

Comment: Thank you so much ! and I was just about to ask regarding storing the class name in a json, and you have already answered that too apparently. My deepest gratitude sir. Need 5 more mins to accept this as answer apparently.

Comment: @Charas Glad I could help

Comment: Okay, so I tried doing this Class.forName("Level001Activity"); but it showed up classNotFoundException, did I do it wrongly ?

Comment: @Charas It needs to be fully-qualified (e.g. `Class.forName("packagename.Level001Activity")`. If you want to put shorter names in the json, you could use a `Map<String, Class<? extends Activity>>` and do for example `map.put("Level001", Level001.class)`.

Comment: classVariable = Class.forName("com.example.ed.pieces.Level001Activity"); Yes, I have tried using the full package name like this and still showing up NotFoundException

Comment: @Charas I don't know why that is. Perhaps you could just do `Class<? extends Activity> clazz = null; if ("Level001".equals(string) { clazz = Level001Activity.class; } else if ("OtherActivity".equals(string)) ... `.

Comment: Well yes that is for the last resort, cause I will have to type possibly more than 100 levels.. Anyway, you have been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Charas I'd ask a separate question about why yo can't get `Class.forName` to work. I've never actually used this method so I don't know the details.

Comment: Sorry I read wrongly, turns out it was unhandled Exception, so the solution is to use try and catch block.

Comment: There are no errors, but when I run the app it keeps crashing with java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference